# Get a specific attribute from pymongo cursor

Tags: flask, pymongo

In the Flask app I'm working on, there is a login endpoint where I need to query the mongodb database and get the user's password. I can retrieve the corresponding user record when username is provided, but I want to get the user's password which is a part of user record.How can I do that?

```
@user.route('/login',methods = ['POST'])
def login():
    user_record = db.user.find({'username': request.json['username']})
    #return password
```

if I try `dumps(user_record)`, I get the following response.

```
[{"_id": {"$oid": "5d785f9537b9d0ebcde1850a"}, "username": "pavindu", "password": {"$binary":
"JDJiJDEyJFZUQ2QzV1RRUmMubmZ1b0FxeTYxdXVkbVYuS09ZWFZJSDFGYzJGbVJMQUllbWdEcFJtZjRx", "$type": "00"}, "createdAt":
{"$date": 1568169877345}}]
```

Since it returns a list, I thought to get the first item and get the value of key 'password'. The below is what I tried and the error I got when testing via POSTman. `dumps(user_record)[0]` returns `[` instead of the dictionary.

```
return dumps(user_record)[0]['password']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

**EDIT**

This is my complete file. I can **query the DB and get results**, but can't get a specific attribute out of it. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
from flask import Flask,request,Blueprint
from database import db
from bson import Binary, Code
from bson.json_util import dumps

user = Blueprint('user', __name__)

@user.route('/login',methods = ['POST'])
def login():
    user_record = db.user.find_one({'username': request.json['username']})
    return dumps(user_record)
```

I want to get the **password** field in `user_record`.How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

I've made some simplifications but this should work for you on python 3.7 / mongo 4.0. If this doesn't work then you have a more fundamental issue to fix first.

```
from bson.json_util import dumps
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime

connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = connection['yourdatabase']

db.testuser.insert_one({"username": "pavindu",
                    "password": "<password>",
                    "createdAt": datetime.datetime.now()})

request = {"username": "pavindu"}

def test_login():
    user_record = db.testuser.find_one({'username': request['username']})
    return dumps(user_record['password'])

print(test_login())
```

Original answer:

Find returns a cursor which you can iterate over. When you use dumps it will iterate over the cursor and create a list which is why you see the results as a list

I suggest you use find_one which returns a single record.

```
@user.route('/login',methods = ['POST'])
def login():
    user_record = db.user.find_one({'username': request.json['username']})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this out. But the problem I have is if `dumps` returns a list, why can't do list operations on that? Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: I'm surprised dumps works at all (I assume it is json.dumps) as it won't be able to encode a cursor object or an ObjectId, so I suspect something else is going on. Are you sure you're not doing list(user_record). What version of python / pymongo are you using?

Comment: I added the full code with imports under **EDIT**. Please check it out..thanks